# AWS cognito verification link issue

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I tried to signup with my email using aws cognito. I received the email verification link and when i clicked on it says 'Invalid link provided, please request a link again'. But when i tried to login it was successful. Why is it happening.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This could be caused by your Email provider visiting links before presenting the email to you. For example Outlook has something called [Safe Links](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/security/office-365-security/safe-links-about?view=o365-worldwide). This will cause the verification link to be consumed before you have a chance to click it.

I had the same issue and after about a day of debugging I reached out to AWS Enterprise Support. Outlook Safe Links is something they mentioned within a few minutes of chatting. If you are a part of a larger organization it is probably unfeasible to have it disabled. You can try signing up with a different Email Provider such as Gmail and see if the links are untouched.

I offer no solution to the problem, just a possible explanation.

Comment: As you don't offer a solution, so write it on comment section of the question!